# rdbuf(...) returns a pointer -- who owns the buffer pointed to?

Tags: c++, stl, streambuf

There is a STL `<ios>` library function

`streambuf* std::basic_ios::rdbuf (streambuf* sb);`

This function can be used to change the stream buffer associated with a stream. If you use this, it returns a pointer to the streambuf that was previously in use. It's not clear who 'owns' the pointer or what its lifetime is. The standard (27.5.5.3/5) simply says

> Returns: the previous value of `rdbuf()`.

which is not very informative. Are there any guarantees about how long this pointer is valid for? Should the calling code `delete` the pointer once it's done with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The buffer is owned by whoever originally installed the buffer into the stream object. A stream object comes with an internal buffer, and a default-constructed stream object uses it by default.

So, unless your code explicitly installed a non-default buffer, using the `rdbuf()` method, the answer is that the buffer is valid as long as the stream object exists.

If you did not install the buffer, you should obviously not `delete` it.

Comment: Thanks -- is this behaviour specified in the standard somewhere?

Comment: Not explicitly. The owner of the buffer returned by rdbuf() is not specified. Obviously, if the caller doesn't own it, it has no business to delete it.

Comment: Also important: even if you installed the buffer and you allocated it with `new`, don't `delete` it until the stream is done with it.